# ¿Problema de conversion de Fechas?

Tags: c#, sql

Bueno mi problema es el siguiente, tengo que guardar un datatble con varios registros entre ellos algunas fechas, y los trato de guardar a travez de un procedimiento almacenado que ejecuta una variable de tipo tabla que es en donde deposito todos mis valores realiza todo el codigo bien excepto por las fechas, aunque si lo inserto manualmente si accede.

Codigo de la llamada del sp:

```
#region Insert_RectificacionesExportaciones
public string Insert_RectificacionesExportaciones(DataTable dt_rectificacionesExportaciones, string empresa)
{
    establecerConexion();
    try
    {
        int idEmpresa = Convert.ToInt16(empresa);
        comando = new SqlCommand("sp_Insert_RectificacionesExportaciones", conexion);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblRectificacionesExportaciones", dt_rectificacionesExportaciones);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@idEmpresa", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idEmpresa;
        comando.CommandTimeout = 7200000;

        conexion.Open();
        comando.ExecuteReader();
        return "1";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return "0";
    }
    finally
    {
        if (comando != null)
            comando.Dispose();
        conexion.Close();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Codigo del SP en BD:

```
USE [DBSIADANA]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Insert_RectificacionesExportaciones]    Script Date: 03/16/2017 12:40:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_RectificacionesExportaciones]
      @tblRectificacionesExportaciones ExpoType READONLY,
      @idEmpresa int
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      MERGE INTO texportacion c1
      USING @tblRectificacionesExportaciones c2
      ON c1.idPedimento = c2.idPedimento
      and c1.idProducto = c2.idProducto
      and c1.factura = c2.factura
      and c1.secuencia= c2.secuencia
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT VALUES(c2.idPedimento,c2.fecha,c2.idCveDocSalida,c2.idTipoCambio,c2.valorComercialUSD,
            c2.valorComercialMNX,c2.valorAduanaMNX,c2.observación,c2.dta,c2.prv,c2.factura,c2.cove,
            c2.fechaFactura,c2.razonSocialCliente,c2.icoterm,c2.idMoneda,c2.factorMonedaExtranjera,
            c2.idProducto,c2.idTipoBien,c2.secuencia,c2.idFraccion,c2.idPaisDestino,c2.idPaisComprador,
            c2.idUnidadComercial,c2.cantidad,c2.precioUnitario,c2.idTasa,c2.preferencia,c2.originalRectificado,
            c2.descargado,c2.fechaIngreso,c2.fechaActualizacion,c2.idUsuario,c2.ipActualizacion,c2.falta,c2.idRemesa,
            c2.numeroPM,c2.fechaRemesa,@idEmpresa); 
END
```

el error que me marca es el siguiente:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The data for table-valued parameter
>   "@tblRectificacionesExportaciones" doesn't conform to the table type
>   of the parameter. The statement has been terminated.

ya verifique que mis campos de fecha si sean de tipo fecha. Algunas fechas son date y otras fechas son datetime.

Las que son fecha de tipo date se guardan asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las que son fechas de tipo datetime son asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bueno, no sabemos nada sobre qué tipos de datos y columnas tiene `@tblRectificacionesExportaciones`. Necesitas dar más detalles

Comment: Al menos podrías usar `SQL Server Profiler` para capturar de que manera estás enviando la información generada en .net y como está llegando al SQL Server. Asimismo, indicarnos el lenguaje de tu instancia donde estás conectado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según veo el mensaje dice que trata de convertir un nvarchar a fecha y este tiene formato incorrecto, si tienes las fechas en string al momento de intentar persistir en SQL debes tener el siguiente formato que si te aceptará:

```
'20170125 15:55:16.783'
```

La fecha de ejemplo corresponde al 25 de enero del 2017 a horas 15:55:16

Comment: muy buena respuesta, gracias